# list comprehension expression error

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to solve this,

```
lst = [['1','2','3'], ['1','2','3','4']]

print [ls for ls in lst if (len(ls)==3) ls.insert(2,"Null")]
```

But it gave the following error,

```
 [ls for ls in lst if (len(ls)==3) ls.insert(2, 'null')]
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You can't have code at that position in a list comprehension?

Answer (score 4):

Using List Comprehension for Side effect is a bad idea. You should use Loop for your purpose

First your syntax is wrong

```
[ls for ls in lst if (len(ls)==3) ls.insert(2, 'null')]
```

should had been written (lets ignore the *bad-idea part*)

```
[ls.insert(2, 'null')  for ls in lst if (len(ls)==3) ]
```

But then, **you would end up creating a list of Nones, a resource waste.**

Instead, you should do

```
for ls in lst:
    if len(ls) == 3:
        ls.insert(2, 'null')
```

Comment: @Downvoter? Can you please leave a comment so that I can understand, whats wrong with the answer?

Comment: I saw the downvote seconds after the first version of your answer. It may have been because it technically wasn't an answer until you included what OP *should* do. But here, I'll give you an upvote to make up for it :)

Comment: Actually I believe the OP wanted to do something like: `[ls for ls in lst if len(ls) == 3 and (ls.insert(2, 'null') or True)]`. However using boolean operators for sequencing operations with side-effects is a big, big hack...

Answer (score 4):

Basically, that's not how list comprehensions work. What they are is, roughly:

```
[ expression for identifier in expression <if condition> ]
```

What you have is:

```
[ expression for identifier in expression if condition expression ]
```

Which isn't valid syntax.

It's also not entirely clear what you want. If you want a *new* list that *only* contains the sublists with len > 3 then you could do:

```
from itertools import chain
new_list = [ list(chain(ls, 'Null')) for ls in lst if len(ls) == 3 ]
```

If you want the result to be the *same* as the original list, only with the len > 3 sublists modified then:

```
from itertools import chain
new_list = [ 
    list(chain(ls, 'Null') if len(ls) == 3 else ls)
    for ls in lst 
]
```

Both of these approaches will leave the original list `lst` **and its sublists** unmodified.

If you *are* intending to modify the original list, then you should definitely be following Abhijit's advice and use a loop.

**Rule of thumb: if you're using a list comprehension and throwing away the result, you really should be using a loop construct.**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
 [ls + (['null'] if len(ls)==3 else []) for ls in lst]
```

This adds an element `'null'` to the end of each sublist of length 3.